# Can't deserialize json: MismatchedInputException. Works with static classes

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, inner-classes

I'm using helping inner class to deserialize some input. Deserialization works when I'm using static classes.

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String message = "{\"location\":\"https://some.com\"}";
        URL url = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(message, Loc.class).getLocation();
        System.out.println(url.toString());
    }

        @Getter
        @Setter
        private class Loc {
            URL location;
        }

}
```

And I get an error when running main class above:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `Test$H$Loc` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor
 at [Source: (String)"{"location":"https://some.com"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
```

When I make classes static all works fine. But I need non-static classes. What wrong?

UPD: I can solve this by making Loc class outer, not an inner class. My question is when I want to do Loc as an inner class why I should make it static for serialization?
UPD: Deleted insignificant inner class H

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need so strange structure? But whatever. If you want such structure, you need to make your `H` class `static` as well as `Loc`:

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String message = "{\"location\":\"https://some.com\"}";
    URL url = new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(message, H.Loc.class).getLocation();
    System.out.println(url.toString());
}

private static class H {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private static class Loc {
        URL location;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote about static in post. I'm using an inner class because it is just helping class for deserialization.

Comment: The main reason Jackson refuse to use non static inner classes for deserialization  is because there is no way to instantiate such classes because there is no non-argument constructor. So Jackson literally can not instantiate them

Comment: More clear: To instantiate Loc class it is necessary to use outer class reference - new Outer().new Inner(). I can't instantiate the inner class without outer class ref. , like new Inner(). Obviously Jackson uses simple non-argument constructor without Outer class reference.

Comment: An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: so what is your question about then?

Comment: There are no more questions) I did not know that it is needed a link to an external class